# Android: onActivityResult in fragment not called

Tags: android, android-fragments

Found numerous post regarding my issue but none of them worked out for me. I have a fragment from where I have to call `startActivityForResult()` on a textview click. From there, an activity will open up where user will fill some data and submit it to database. From there, I have to pass an intent containing the result code. But the onActivityResult() in fragment is not get called.

**Code from my fragment**

```
Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), NetBarrelActivity.class);
        in.putExtra(AppUtility.ORDER_ID, orderDAO.getOrderNum());
        in.putExtra(AppUtility.TICKET_ID, 2);
        startActivityForResult(in, AppUtility.REQUEST_CODE);
```

**Code from my activity**

```
Double NetBarrels = crudeNetCalculator(GrossBarrels,
                        ProductObsTemp, ProductObsGravity, ProductBSW);
                db.updateTank(OrderID, TicketTypeID, CarrierTicketNum,
                        TankNum, TankTypeID, ProductObsTemp,
                        ProductObsGravity, ProductBSW, GrossBarrels,
                        NetBarrels);
                Intent in = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, in);
                finish();
```

onActivityResult in Fragment:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityReslt called");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case AppUtility.REQUEST_CODE:
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if (mOrdersDAO.getTicketType().equals(AppUtility.NET_BARREL)) {
                ArrayList<OrderTicketsDao> mOrderTicketsDaos = dbHandler
                        .getOrderTicket(mOrdersDAO.getOrderNum());
                if (mOrderTicketsDaos != null && mOrderTicketsDaos.size() > 0) {
                    TankAdapter mTankAdapter = new TankAdapter(getActivity(),
                            mOrderTicketsDaos);
                    listTank.setAdapter(mTankAdapter);
                    mTankAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

So, how do I send intent back to my fragment with result code?

Comment: You should be able to find a solution for your problem [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: Thanks, I already visited the link. Did n't worked

Comment: Although I am bit late, but this is how it has worked for me, implement the `onActivityResult()` in the `Activity` itself, receive the `Intent` extras and pass them to a method of `Fragment` which does relevant stuff on updating or retrieving data.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since, I wanted to my fragment to intercept the intent so I used [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).

In `onCreate` of Fragment, I defined:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
            mUpdateUIReceiver,
            new IntentFilter(String action));
```

My receiver in fragment:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mUpdateUIReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //do Stuff
    }
};
```

Activity code which will send broadcast:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(
            new Intent(String action));
```

Hope it helps someone who is facing same problem.

Comment: I find this to be a very clean way to pass results when using fragments and childfragments. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for very useful answer that solved my problem! I needed also to send some text from another activity to fragment, which can be easily done with adding extra values to intent.